# How to add buildscript dependencies in custom plugin to project dependency?

Tags: gradle

I wrote a custom gradle plugin which comes with an additional compile step. For the compilation some classes of the plugin itself are needed, since it is an annotation processor.

I try to solve it by adding the plugin as a compile dependency this way:

```
// in the custom plugin 
project.dependencies {
  compile "com.thilko.spring:gradle-springdoc-plugin:0.1.SNAPSHOT"
  compile localGroovy()
}
```

This solution is working but introduces duplication since I have to declare the same plugin version that is already declared in the build script section of the project that uses the plugin:

```
// build.gradle of the project that uses the plugin
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.thilko.spring:gradle-springdoc-plugin:0.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'springdoc'
```

Is there a way to reuse the dependencies defined in the buildscript section?

Comment: Are these snippets taken from the plugins' build script? Who is affected by the duplication? Only the plugin author, or each user of the plugin?

Comment: Its from the plugin buildscript, affected is just plugin owner.

Comment: Both snippets? Why do you say "of the parent project"? Is this a multi-project build? You'd have to explain in more detail.

Comment: Sorry about that. With "parent project" I just mean the project that uses the plugin. It´s just a plugin that comes with an additional compile task and for the compilation I need classes from the plugin itself. The first snippet is a working snippet, and the second is just a tryout to use the dependencies defined in buildscript section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's worth it, you can declare an extra property inside the `buildscript` block (e.g. `ext.springdocPlugin = "com.thilko.spring:gradle-springdoc-plugin:0.1.SNAPSHOT"`), and then reuse it from outside (e.g. `dependencies { compile buildscript.springdocPlugin }`).

Answer (score 1):

If you add the dependency to the pom of the your plugin, it will be added to the buildscript dependencies of the project you apply your plugin to.